# Swap output in last x minutes

Tags: swap

Is there any command or script to give o/p as " swap used in last 10 minutes is x" ?
I wished to use that out put for my nagios monitoring..

I have used SAR in my below script and is trying to run on individual servers for my nagios monitoring.
Can someone please suggest how i can get the swap warning and swap critical values in my check below ? I have tried to calculate it dynamically when running the below on each server but it is reporting for error.

Please suggest.

```
# 2 = CRITICAL (SWAP usage higher than CRITICAL)
# 3 = UNKNOWN (Wrong usage)

SWAP_WARN=
SWAP_CRIT=
SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST=

## GET SWAP Warning and Critical values from the Machine

# 2 = CRITICAL (SWAP usage higher than CRITICAL)
# 3 = UNKNOWN (Wrong usage)

SWAP_WARN=
SWAP_CRIT=
SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST=

**## GET SWAP Warning and Critical values from the Machine
temp=$(swapon -s | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $3}' )
SWAP_WARN=$(echo '$(temp)*.20' | bc)
SWAP_CRIT=$(echo '$(temp)*.40' | bc)**

## FETCH ARGUMENTS
##while getopts "h:" OPTION; do
#        case "${h}" in
#                 h)
#                        usage
#                        exit 3
#                        ;;
#                ?)
#                        usage
#                        exit 3
#                        ;;
#        esac
#done

## CHECK ARGUMENTS
if [ -z ${SWAP_WARN} ] || [ -z ${SWAP_CRIT} ] || [ ${SWAP_WARN} -gt ${SWAP_CRIT} ] ; then
        usage
        exit 3
fi

## GET SWAP INFO FROM MACHINE

cd /var/log/sa
FOR_VALUE=sa
FOR_DATE=$(date | awk '{print $3}')
SA=$FOR_VALUE$FOR_DATE
SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST=$(sar -S -f $SA | tail -n 2| head -n 1 | awk '{print $4}')


## CHECK SWAPPING ON MACHINE
if [ ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} -lt ${SWAP_WARN} ]; then
        ## SWAP IS OK
        LINE="OK! Swapout size in last 10 minutes : ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} | swapout_size=${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST}B;${SWAP_WARN};${SWAP_CRIT};"
        echo $LINE
        exit 0
elif [ ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} -gt ${SWAP_WARN} ] && [ ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} -lt ${SWAP_CRIT} ] || [ ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} -eq ${SWAP_WARN} ]; then
        ## SWAP IS IN WARNING STATE
        LINE="WARNING! Swapout size in last 10 minutes: ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} | swapout_size=${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST}B;${SWAP_WARN};${SWAP_CRIT};"
:

## FETCH ARGUMENTS
##while getopts "h:" OPTION; do
#        case "${h}" in
#                 h)
#                        usage
#                        exit 3
#                        ;;
#                ?)
#                        usage
#                        exit 3
#                        ;;
#        esac
#done

## CHECK ARGUMENTS
if [ -z ${SWAP_WARN} ] || [ -z ${SWAP_CRIT} ] || [ ${SWAP_WARN} -gt ${SWAP_CRIT} ] ; then
        usage
        exit 3
fi

## GET SWAP INFO FROM MACHINE

cd /var/log/sa
FOR_VALUE=sa
FOR_DATE=$(date | awk '{print $3}')
SA=$FOR_VALUE$FOR_DATE
SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST=$(sar -S -f $SA | tail -n 2| head -n 1 | awk '{print $4}')


## CHECK SWAPPING ON MACHINE
if [ ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} -lt ${SWAP_WARN} ]; then
        ## SWAP IS OK
        LINE="OK! Swapout size in last 10 minutes : ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} | swapout_size=${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST}B;${SWAP_WARN};${SWAP_CRIT};"
        echo $LINE
        exit 0
elif [ ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} -gt ${SWAP_WARN} ] && [ ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} -lt ${SWAP_CRIT} ] || [ ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} -eq ${SWAP_WARN} ]; then
        ## SWAP IS IN WARNING STATE
        LINE="WARNING! Swapout size in last 10 minutes: ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} | swapout_size=${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST}B;${SWAP_WARN};${SWAP_CRIT};"
:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can collect such info via setting sar in cron. And then create custom probe in nagios to read sar results from last 10 minutes

Answer (score -1):

Try this command.. it will give u the information about swap usage for every 10 minutes

> sar -W -f /var/log/sa/sa(date)

Sample output

05:00:01 AM  pswpin/s pswpout/s
05:10:03 AM      0.00      0.77
05:20:03 AM     10.00     45.08
05:30:02 AM     10.38      1.36
Average:         7.18     16.38

Comment: Siva, to get this information you need to collect info before (as I describe in my answer)

Comment: Hi, Can someone please help me with the question at the below link ?     http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214788/how-to-calculate-swap-warning-critical-dynamically-through-script