# How to calculate Swap warning/critical dynamically through script?

Tags: scripting, swap, nagios

I have used SAR in my below script and is trying to run on individual servers for my nagios monitoring. 
Can someone please suggest how i can get the swap warning and swap critical values in my check below ? I have tried to calculate it dynamically when running the below on each server but it is reporting for error.

> (Swap warning/critical needs to be calculated like 20% of Total
>   swap/40 % of total swap respectively)

Please suggest.

```
# 2 = CRITICAL (SWAP usage higher than CRITICAL)
# 3 = UNKNOWN (Wrong usage)

SWAP_WARN=
SWAP_CRIT=
SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST=

## GET SWAP Warning and Critical values from the Machine

# 2 = CRITICAL (SWAP usage higher than CRITICAL)
# 3 = UNKNOWN (Wrong usage)

SWAP_WARN=
SWAP_CRIT=
SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST=

**## GET SWAP Warning and Critical values from the Machine
temp=$(swapon -s | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $3}' )
SWAP_WARN=$(echo '$(temp)*.20' | bc)
SWAP_CRIT=$(echo '$(temp)*.40' | bc)**

## FETCH ARGUMENTS
##while getopts "h:" OPTION; do
#        case "${h}" in
#                 h)
#                        usage
#                        exit 3
#                        ;;
#                ?)
#                        usage
#                        exit 3
#                        ;;
#        esac
#done

## CHECK ARGUMENTS
if [ -z ${SWAP_WARN} ] || [ -z ${SWAP_CRIT} ] || [ ${SWAP_WARN} -gt ${SWAP_CRIT} ] ; then
        usage
        exit 3
fi

## GET SWAP INFO FROM MACHINE

cd /var/log/sa
FOR_VALUE=sa
FOR_DATE=$(date | awk '{print $3}')
SA=$FOR_VALUE$FOR_DATE
SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST=$(sar -S -f $SA | tail -n 2| head -n 1 | awk '{print $4}')


## CHECK SWAPPING ON MACHINE
if [ ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} -lt ${SWAP_WARN} ]; then
        ## SWAP IS OK
        LINE="OK! Swapout size in last 10 minutes : ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} | swapout_size=${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST}B;${SWAP_WARN};${SWAP_CRIT};"
        echo $LINE
        exit 0
elif [ ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} -gt ${SWAP_WARN} ] && [ ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} -lt ${SWAP_CRIT} ] || [ ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} -eq ${SWAP_WARN} ]; then
        ## SWAP IS IN WARNING STATE
        LINE="WARNING! Swapout size in last 10 minutes: ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} | swapout_size=${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST}B;${SWAP_WARN};${SWAP_CRIT};"
:

## FETCH ARGUMENTS
##while getopts "h:" OPTION; do
#        case "${h}" in
#                 h)
#                        usage
#                        exit 3
#                        ;;
#                ?)
#                        usage
#                        exit 3
#                        ;;
#        esac
#done

## CHECK ARGUMENTS
if [ -z ${SWAP_WARN} ] || [ -z ${SWAP_CRIT} ] || [ ${SWAP_WARN} -gt ${SWAP_CRIT} ] ; then
        usage
        exit 3
fi

## GET SWAP INFO FROM MACHINE

cd /var/log/sa
FOR_VALUE=sa
FOR_DATE=$(date | awk '{print $3}')
SA=$FOR_VALUE$FOR_DATE
SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST=$(sar -S -f $SA | tail -n 2| head -n 1 | awk '{print $4}')


## CHECK SWAPPING ON MACHINE
if [ ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} -lt ${SWAP_WARN} ]; then
        ## SWAP IS OK
        LINE="OK! Swapout size in last 10 minutes : ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} | swapout_size=${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST}B;${SWAP_WARN};${SWAP_CRIT};"
        echo $LINE
        exit 0
elif [ ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} -gt ${SWAP_WARN} ] && [ ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} -lt ${SWAP_CRIT} ] || [ ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} -eq ${SWAP_WARN} ]; then
        ## SWAP IS IN WARNING STATE
        LINE="WARNING! Swapout size in last 10 minutes: ${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST} | swapout_size=${SWAPOUT_ACTIVITY_TEST}B;${SWAP_WARN};${SWAP_CRIT};"
```

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason you cannot use `check_swap` from [nagios-plugins](https://www.nagios.org/download/plugins)?

```
check_swap -w 80% -c 60%
```

If you insist on using `sar`, why calculate an absolute value for the threshold at all, can't you just use the value from the `%swpused` column to determine check state?

```
SWPUSED=$(sar -S -f $SA | tail -2 | head -1 | awk '{print $5}')
SWPUSED_ROUNDED=$(printf "%.0f" $SWPUSED)

if [ $SWPUSED_ROUNDED -gt 40 ]; then
    echo "CRITICAL: ${SWPUSED}% of swap space used"
    exit 2
elif [ $SWPUSED_ROUNDED -gt 20 ]; then
    echo "WARNING: ${SWPUSED}% of swap space used"
    exit 1
else
    echo "OK: ${SWPUSED}% of swap space used"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: I need to get Nagios output/alert as "Swap usage in last "x" minutes is " ....                    And due to the reason i am using SAR outputs for my alert...as they are generated every '10' minutes by default....

Comment: Yes, but the sampling period depends on the crontab entry you added... How often are you calling `sa1` from cron? Can you paste the relevant line here?

Comment: thanks....but the sampling in not my problem at all.............i am asking how could i calculate two values  swap_war and swap_crit below (using the above mentioned script)  ????????????                                                                                                                                                                             ## GET SWAP Warning and Critical values from the Machine
temp=$(swapon -s | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $3}' )
SWAP_WARN=$(echo '$(temp)*.20' | bc)
SWAP_CRIT=$(echo '$(temp)*.40' | bc)

Comment: Updated my answer, see if it works for you.

Comment: Many thanks kempniu. The numbers "40" and "20" are constant(fixed), As i don't know what is Swap warning/swap critical levels defined on each of my servers(that i will monitor through this script) . i need to calculate these values as 20 and 40 % respectively of the total swap on each server and hence the logic.....


Can you please suggest now ?

Comment: Not sure I follow. The values 40 and 20 in my script are percentages (note I used `$5` instead of `$4` in my `awk` script) calculated by `sar`. Why would you want to do the math yourself if you don't have to?

Comment: Ok... i will check and will update how it follows...Thanks.

Comment: So? Did it work?